# C# random image in picturebox and assign value

Tags: c#

I'm creating a card game using C#. I want to assign a value to my card example: Ace(image) = 1; and I want to random it. Here's my code:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random cards = new Random();
            card = cards.Next(0, 9);
            switch (card)
            {
                case 0:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.king_d;
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.jack_s;

                    break;

                case 1:
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.ace_c;
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.ten_d;

                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should load the images to an array once and then assign to the pictureboxes from that, or dispose of the previous image, if any,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

new the random out of the method. you can take it from a singleton class ([read this](http://www.dotnetperls.com/singleton)) or for simplicity if you are in windows app make it static like this:

```
static Random cards = new Random();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        card = cards.Next(0, 9);
        switch (card)
        {
            case 0:
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.king_d;
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.jack_s;

                break;

            case 1:
                pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.ace_c;
                pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.ten_d;

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**
The best way to have a card that contains a value, picture, etc. is to have a new class for that. Since PictureBox already has most properties and behaviors that you need, I recommend using it.

The code has to be something like this:

```
   Public Class MyCard:PictureBox
    {
      public int GamePoint {get;set;}
    }
```

Then instead of using PictureBox in your code, use this.

To be honest I like to encapsulate the code a bit more so I prefer this:

```
   Public Class MyCard:PictureBox
    {
      public CardType CardType {set;get;}
      public int GamePoint {get{ return (int)this.CardType;  }}
      public MyCard(CardType _cardType)
      {
       CardType = _cardType;
        }
    }

    enum CardType
    { Ace=1,
    King=2,
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, sir! How bout assigning a value to image? Example: I want the Ace(image) = 1 ?

Comment: @VyanAxel inherit from Picturebox, then add an int property to that. I will describe in the answere

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't see an actual question in your question, I think you want to do this in a simpler way.

Well first of all, don't create a `Random` every time the method is called, make it a class-level variable and initialize it:

```
private static Random cards = new Random();
```

Currently, you're using a `switch` to decide what to show in the two picture boxes. If the random number is 0, put these two cards, if the number is 1, put those two cards... This means that each number from 0 to 9 corresponds to two `Bitmap`s.

You can use a dictionary to map 0 to 9 to `Tuple<Bitmap, Bitmap>`, but I think it's better to use an array.

What you basically need to do is to declare an array that stores those `Tuple<Bitmap, Bitmap>`. Let's call it `CardCombinations`. I recommend you to put this array in a utility class called `CardUtility` or something. Then, you can just do:

```
card = cards.Next(0, 9);
pictureBox1.Image = CardUtility.CardCombinations[card].Item1;
pictureBox2.Image = CardUtility.CardCombinations[card].Item2;
```

As you can see, this greatly reduced the code in the `button1_Click` method. Now we can declare the array that I was talking about.

It's pretty simple:

```
public static Tuple<Bitmap, Bitmap>[] CardCombinations => new[] {
    new Tuple<Bitmap, Bitmap>(Properties.Resources.king_d, Properties.Resources.jack_s),
    ...
};
```

"But that's still verbose!" you cried. Protip: you can use the `using static` directive to shorten the bitmap names to `king_d` and `jack_s`!

```
using static SomeNamespace.Properties.Resources;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer though I'm not familiar with those words. Hmm, How about assigning value in image? Can you help me sir? Thank you for your response

Comment: @VyanAxel Of course I would help you! But you need to tell me what problems you had when using the code and instructions I provided before I can explain further!